# SimpleBlobDetector detect Exception Thrown

Tags: c++, opencv, c++-cli

I am using SimpleBlobDetector, of course to detect circles, in images grabbed from a camera and have undergone OpenCV color and morphological filters. I am receiving an

> Exception thrown at 0x000... (opencv_imgproc249.dll) in .exe: Access violation reading location 0x000...

I am receiving this error on the line containing: `d.detect(canny, keypoints);`
Here is a sample of my code:

```
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
SimpleBlobDetector d(params);
d.detect(canny, keypoints);
drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, im_with_keypoints, Scalar(0, 255, 0), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
```

`canny` is from the utilization of `Canny(input, canny, 10, 30);`

Can anyone potentially explain why I might be receiving this error?

EDIT:

I realized I was using the method of keypoint detection for OpenCV version < 3. I have since changed it to:

```
Ptr<SimpleBlobDetector> d = SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);
std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
d->detect(thresh, keypoints);
drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, im_with_keypoints, Scalar(0, 255, 0), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
```

However, now I have an error related to `params`. The following error reads:

> E0312 - no suitable user defined conversion from "cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params" to "const std::string" exists

I have copied this exactly from [SimpleBlobDetector Tutorial](https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/) and oddly have this issue.

Comment: You might have hit a bug in OpenCV. Make sure you are on the latest version.

Comment: More accurately, the dynamic link library(DLL) ***opencv_imgproc249.dll*** is not built properly and cannot find the proper definition of the member method `detect()`... You should build OpenCV again...

Comment: @RolandWeber & Ruks - Thank you both. I realized I was using the incorrect method of drawing keypoints, I have since changed the method for OpenCV versions greater than 3. I have since encountered a new issue. Please refer to EDIT made to the original post. Thx