# Issue Initializing Parameters of SimpleBlobDetector

Tags: c++, opencv, c++-cli

Here is my code:

```
SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
//Filter by Area
params.filterByArea = true;
params.minArea = 5000;              //Filters out areas less than 5000 pixels.
//Filter by Circularity.
params.filterByCircularity = true;  //Circle has circularity = 1.000
params.minCircularity = 0.79F;      //Square has circularity = 0.785
//Filter by Convexity
params.filterByConvexity = true;
params.minConvexity = 0.10F;
//Filter by Inertia
params.filterByInertia = true;
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01F;

Ptr<SimpleBlobDetector> d = SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
d->detect(processed_src, keypoints);
drawKeypoints(src, keypoints, im_with_keypoints, Scalar(0, 255, 0), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
```

I am drawing my information directly from SimpleBlobDetector tutorials for OpenCV versions >=3. I am receiving the following error being called from `Ptr<SimpleBlobDetector> d = SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);` Apparently, params is not being set properly. See the following error message:

> E0312 - no suitable user-defined conversion from "cv::SimpleBlobDetector::Params" to "const std::string" exists

Can anyone explain why this is? I have used SimpleBlobDetector is past projects and have had no issues.

Comment: What is the version of opencv that you are using?

Comment: @RickM. Currently not at the computer I have my work on, but I am pretty sure its running with 3.4.3

Comment: well if you are running the 3.4.3 this shouldn't be invoked. I'd expect this error for opencv version < 3

Comment: @RickM. Agreed, I will have to check exactly which version I am using once I get back to my work computer. I appreciate your aid.

Comment: Duplicate of post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53202635/simpleblobdetector-detect-exception-thrown